# Lottery Program Ignores Function

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I'm meant to write a program that lists one random number after the other, which it does (along with a beep). However, it ignores a fundamental function needed for the program to run correctly. The ask() function does what it implies, it asks the user to input an integer between the range (1000-9999) which is then compared to the winning number (random) to see if the user correctly guessed it and thus won. I've only recently started writing in Java so I'm not very sure if there's a basic mistake I'm making. Any help would be appreciated!

```
package edu.pupr.pega4;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Pega4Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pega4 test = new Pega4(2000, true);
        test.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit program?");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Perdiste!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class Pega4 {
    private int interval; //Time interval for new number to appear
    private boolean beep; //BEEP
    private int number; //The input number
    private int tiradas = 1; //Counter
    private int winNum; //The winning number 
    //Constructor
    public Pega4(int interval, boolean beep) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.beep = beep;
    }
    //Returns a random number within a specified range
    public double getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(double min, double max){
        double x = (int)(Math.random()*((max-min)+1))+min;
        return x;
    }
    public void start() {
        class Pega4Inner implements Asker, ActionListener {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Date now = new Date();
            @Override
            public void ask() {
                System.out.println("Entrar numero deseado: ");
                number = input.nextInt();
                //Input Validation
                if (number < 1000 || number > 9999)
                {
                    System.out.println("Entrada invalida. Entrar numero deseado: ");
                    number = input.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println(now);
            }
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                winNum = (int) getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(1000, 9999);
                System.out.println("Tirada #" + (tiradas++) + ": " + winNum);
                if (beep)
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                if (winNum == number)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ganaste!!!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        ActionListener listener = new Pega4Inner();
        Timer timer = new Timer(interval, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

The Pega4Inner class implements an interface named Asker created by me. Its code is as follows:

```
package edu.pupr.pega4;

public interface Asker {
    void ask();
}
```

Comment: *"it ignores a fundamental function needed for the program to run correctly."*. Okay - **what is it ignoring/doing wrong**?

Comment: I think it would help if you'd actually call your ask method...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to actually call your `ask()` method from somewhere :)
I think a proper point to do that in your current code would be in the beginning of your `actionPerformed()` method in `Pega4Inner` :

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     ask();
     winNum = (int) getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(1000, 9999);
     …
```

**EDIT**

Based on your requirement to call `ask()` only once, one way to do it is by taking this method out of your inner class and put it in your outer class, then call it explicitly in your driver class. So your `Pega4` class could look like this :

```
class Pega4 {
    private int interval; //Time interval for new number to appear
    private boolean beep; //BEEP
    private int number; //The input number
    private int tiradas = 1; //Counter
    private int winNum; //The winning number 
    //Constructor
    Date now = new Date();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Pega4(int interval, boolean beep) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.beep = beep;
    }

    //Returns a random number within a specified range
    public double getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(double min, double max) {
        double x = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
        return x;
    }

    public void ask() {
        System.out.println("Entrar numero deseado: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        //Input Validation
        while (number < 1000 || number > 9999) { // not IF here
            System.out.println("Entrada invalida. Entrar numero deseado: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(now);
    }

    public void start() {
        class Pega4Inner implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ask();
                winNum = (int) getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(1000, 9999);
                System.out.println("Tirada #" + (tiradas++) + ": " + winNum);
                if (beep) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
                if (winNum == number) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ganaste!!!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        ActionListener listener = new Pega4Inner();
        Timer timer = new Timer(interval, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

And then in your `Pega4Driver` class :

```
...
Pega4 test = new Pega4(2000, true);
test.ask();
test.start();
...
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't run as desired. When I call the ask() function like that, the program asks the user for the input, generates a random number, and then asks the user for a number again. It should only ask once, then generate the list of random numbers until the user quits or the number matches the user input.

Comment: Just also note that the sanity check in your `ask()` checking whether the input is within the desired range (1000 - 9999) works only once (eg if you enter an invalid number a second time it will accept it). So I also switched the `if` to `while` for this